# Unsupported Curve during SSL Handshake

Tags: java, security, ssl, nginx

I have a piece of java code that is trying to connect to an nginx web server.  It does this:

```
  String url = HTTP_PROTOCOL + modifyForIpv6hostname) + GET_ROOT_CA_PATH;
  try
  {
     HttpURLConnection conn = httpConnection.getHTTPConnection( url, user, password );
     conn.setRequestMethod( "GET" );
     conn.setRequestProperty( "Accept", "text/plain" );
     conn.connect();//this is the line that fails
```

Nothing particularly fancy is going on, and this code previously worked against other web servers.

```
    public HttpURLConnection getHTTPConnection(String urlString, String username, String password) throws IOException, KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    trustAllHttpsCertificates();
    HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {
        public boolean verify(String urlHostName, SSLSession session) {
           return true;
        }
    };
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    if( username != null && password != null ) {
        String userPassword = username + ":" + password;
        String encoding = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userPassword.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        conn.setRequestProperty( "Authorization", "Basic " + encoding );
    }
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(DEFAULT_HTTP_TIMEOUT);
    return conn;
}

protected static void trustAllHttpsCertificates() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
    javax.net.ssl.TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new javax.net.ssl.TrustManager[1];
    javax.net.ssl.TrustManager tm = new miTM();
    trustAllCerts[0] = tm;
    javax.net.ssl.SSLContext sc = javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, null);
    javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
}

public static class miTM implements javax.net.ssl.TrustManager, javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager {
    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return null;
    }
    public boolean isServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs) {
        return true;
    }
    public boolean isClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs) {
        return true;
    }
    public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
        throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
        return;
    }
    public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
        throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
        return;
    }
}
```

The stack trace I'm getting is:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Unsupported curve: 1.2.840.10045.3.1.7
  at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeMessage$ECDH_ServerKeyExchange.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
```

My understanding is fairly limited here, but the gist is that the server does not support the given curve, correct?  How do I, or can I, configure nginx to handle this curve?  I can provide more details (lists of the openssl ciphers, openssl versions, java versions, etc) if they would help, but I am not sure they are necessary.

Comment: Very likely you are having an issue with Elliptic Curve cryptography cipher suites. It means during SSL handshake client and the server fail to negotiate which cipher suite to use. Very likely the problem on the client site- SSL framework which is in use by Java application. Can you please enable java SSL debugs and post it here so we can better help you ?

Comment: What exactly am I looking for?  I'm hesitant to post thousands of lines of log files.

Comment: try to look for handshake and cipher suites information.